# Radeon 9200 Driver?

Tags: drivers, radeon, ati

I've been using Linux for a while, but haven't really done more than installed programs.  I have Ubuntu 12.04 with an ATI Radeon 9200 graphics card.  Ubuntu didn't recognize it during the install.  All I want is a driver.  Preferably the proprietary driver, but I'll settle for an open-source one if I need to.  I went to the AMD support website, and whenever I click on the download link for "ATI Proprietary Linux x86 Display Driver 8.28.8"  I get redirected to the main AMD website.  I tried this on Firefox, Chrome, even booted up my netbook and tried it on IE9.  Does anybody have a download link?  And if not, a link to download an open-source alternative?  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  I'm pretty much still a newbie at this.

```
OpenGL vendor string: Tungsten Graphics, Inc. 
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI R200 (RV280 5961) x86/MMX/SSE2 TCL DRI2 
OpenGL version string: 1.3 Mesa 8.0.2 
Not software rendered: yes 
Not blacklisted: yes 
GLX fbconfig: yes 
GLX texture from pixmap: yes 
GL npot or rect textures: yes 
GL vertex program: yes 
GL fragment program: no 
GL vertex buffer object: yes 
GL framebuffer object: yes 
GL version is 1.4+: no 
Unity 3D supported: no
```

Comment: So I tried the command and I got:

OpenGL vendor string:   Tungsten Graphics, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI R200 (RV280 5961) x86/MMX/SSE2 TCL DRI2
OpenGL version string:  1.3 Mesa 8.0.2





Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      no
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       no

Unity 3D supported:       no

Comment: How do I know if a driver is being used for it, or if it's just being treated as a standard VGA adapter?

Comment: Search for `additional drivers` from dash. When started it will show a list of available drivers. You can `activate` one if none are or another drives if one is. But please stick to the recommended.

Comment: From that info you know that it is recognizing your card, what makes you say otherwise? AMD (ATI as it was known back then) stopped supporting the card *ages* ago so there is no Proprietary drivers (Catalyst) by the way, when you boot Ubuntu without installing any drivers the open source drivers (for any brand of card) are used.

Answer (score 2):

Try this version of Catalyst, it's working well with Gnome3: http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.run

Comment: this didn't work for me, I got an unusable system until I uninstalled Catalyst.

Answer (score 0):

There is no proprietary driver for this card because AMD think it's not worth it to support it. You have to use the open source radeon driver.